# How to change a numeric value with given conditions

Tags: php

I had a test this week about php code. And there is a question still bothering me. Normally I wouldn't ask these questions here but this is it:

You have to make a divider sum with just `min()` `max()` and `print()`

You cannot use `if` statements (`==, <=, >=`).

You always have to divide the big number by the smaller number but if the small number is 0 or lower it has to be changed to 1.

My answer was something like:

```
$min = min($num1, $num2);
$max = max($num1, $num2);

Print($max/$min);
```

But how do you decide when the 0 has to be determined to 1 with the given conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but if the small number is 0 or lower it has to be changed to 1

So, in other words - the **maximum** of this number, and 1 …

```
max(-1, 1); // -> 1
max( 0, 1); // -> 1
max( 1, 1); // -> 1
max( 2, 1); // -> 2
...
```

Comment: Oh shit I had not even thought about this yet :o ill try it out

Comment: Jup this works, for some reason I hadent thought of this because I thought it had something to do with the given values. Thanks a lot